# Stock Ticker Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

[image]

I  had created a loop that runs through and count yearly change for each ticker. I am not getting the right value for second ticker "AA" as mentioned in the picture.
I am trying to get the loop running through all the data and get the value of year open and year close and that gives me yearly change for each stock

here is my code:

```
Private Sub easy()

    Dim ticker As String
    Dim vol As Double
    vol = 0

    Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
    Dim year_open As Double
    Dim year_close As Double

    Cells(1, 9).Value = "ticker"
    Cells(1, 10).Value = "Yearly_change"
    Cells(1, 12).Value = "Total Stock Vol"
    Cells(1, 11).Value = "Yearly_percentage"

    Summary_Table_Row = 2

    For i = 2 To 797712

      If year_open = 0 Then

          year_open = Cells(i, 3).Value
      End If

      If Cells(i - 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) And Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
          year_close = Cells(i, 6).Value
          yearly_change = year_close - year_open


          ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value


          vol = vol + Cells(i, 7).Value



          Range("j" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = yearly_change


          Range("I" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = ticker

          Range("K" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = year_percent



          Range("L" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = vol

          Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1

          vol = 0


      Else

          vol = vol + Cells(i, 7).Value


      End If


    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using VBA but array formulas to compute the ticker min and max dates with corresponding minimum *Open* and maximum *Close* value row numbers. Finally the desired column, *YearDiff* uses an `INDEX/MATCH` formula based on above calculated row numbers.

To demonstrate, below is screenshot using random data with calculated columns: *MinOpen*, *MinDate*, *MaxClose*, *MaxDate*. Corresponding formulas for first row follows further below.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet Screenshot]

```
YearDiff : =INDEX($A$1:$F$21, O2, 6) - INDEX($A$1:$F$21, L2, 3)

MinOpen  : {=MATCH(I2&M2,A:A&B:B,0)} 
MinDate  : {=MIN(IF(A:A=$I2,B:B))}

MaxClose : {=MIN(IF(A:A=$I2,B:B))}
MaxDate  : {=MAX(IF(A:A=$I2,B:B))}
```

Note: to create an array formula shown with braces, type the equality expression in cell then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. From there, drag down the formulas for other rows.